# Thermal vs Thermic

Tags: terminology

**Thermal** vs **Thermic**

Which one of this two terms is the most correct as an adjective meaning "relative to temperature" ?

If neither are, which one is the most used in a scientific context ? Do they relate to slightly different things ?

*Note : For anyone wondering why I'm concerned with this question, I'm a computer scientist concerned about maintaining coherence between different filenames, which some are currently labeled as "thermic" and other as "thermal".*

Comment: You may also consider making this question in https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/ask/advice?

Comment: I did consider it, but it is its usage in a scientific context that really interests me here. I'm going to edit to "in a scientific context" after "most used". However, it may still be interesting to have the take of english stackexchange on this question. I'll keep it in mind !

Comment: I have no evidence other than my own personal experience as a physicist and native English speaker, which is why this isn't an answer, but "thermic" is a word I've only ever seen used when heat is used as part of a technology (see "thermic lance"), whereas "thermal" is a more general term describing anything relating to heat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither.

Like @pobably_someone I have never heard the term "thermic" in connection with "temperature". According to Wikipedia the term thermic was once used for "thermodynamics", and sometimes refers to an "exothermic" or "endothermic" process.

The term "thermal" is a term to avoid since it is frequently used as an adjective for energy ("thermal energy"). Temperature is not energy. Using the term "thermal" in connection with "temperature" fosters the confusion between temperature and energy. Temperature can be considered a measure of the average kinetic energy of the molecules in an object or a system, but it is not the energy itself.

> It goes out of the scope of the question now, but what adjective would
>   you suggest to use to express "relative to temperature" then ?

I'm a bit hesitant about suggesting a single term as it might be construed as a definition of temperature and it is unclear to me how the "filename" will be used in connection with the term "temperature" (I'm not a programmer). That being said, then the term that comes to mind as a "key word" relating to the term temperature is ***kinetic***, which is defined as follows (Oxford-adjective):

*relating to or resulting from motion.*

Moreover, the term "kinetic temperature" has a definite meaning in thermodynamics and is associated with the kinetic theory of gases.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you ! You seem to induce that they're both flawed terms to express "relative to temperature". It goes out of the scope of the question now, but what adjective would you suggest to use to express "relative to temperature" then ?

Comment: @021 I have updated my answer to make a suggestion.

Comment: But temperature is not (proportional to) kinetic energy. I may use "thermal energy" sometimes. Yesterday I wrote a comment here on SE saying that the thermal kinetic energy of a diatomic molecule is almost entirely due to the nuclei.

Comment: "Translational" temperature is the one I would have picked, but that may be more specific than "kinetic" since I guess one could include rotational temperature under a "kinetic" umbrella. As you note, though, being overly specific is probably not the intent for a filename though.

Comment: @tpg2114 I considered "translational" but was concerned that it might be connected with translation as in language as opposed to motion. Then I considered "translational kinetic energy" but ruled that out because it could be construed as equating temperature with energy. I then settled on "kinetic" because the term "kinetic temperature"  because it is specifically limited to translational kinetic energy and not rotational or vibrational modes. Oh well, this is what happens when you try an use a single term. It is best thought of as a key word.

Comment: @Pieter Oxford definition of "relative" as an adjective is "considered in relation or in proportion to something else". I was using the "considered in relation" aspect, not proportional. But anyway technically "temperature" is proportional to kinetic energy for ideal gases when we refer to "kinetic temperature" (internal energy) with $C_v$ being the proportionality constant.  As far as "thermal energy" is concerned, noted author of Heat and Thermodynamics  Mark Zemansky recommends avoiding the term considering it too vague.

Comment: I totally agree that "thermal energy" is often insufficiently precise, especially in the context of thermodynamics. But sometimes one wants to distinguish between the extra energy due to finite temperature and all the kinetic energy that is in the electron system in the ground state.

Comment: @Pieter I'm not conversant in quantum mechanics. Can you briefly educate me on what the "kinetic energy that is in the electron system in the ground state" means? Is this kinetic energy reflected in the macroscopic property of temperature? Thanks.

Comment: It is just the kinetic energy of the electrons in atoms and molecules. It is large: about 10 eV per electron or more. But it is irrelevant when one talks about the heat capacity etcetera.

Comment: @Pieter Thanks a lot for the explanation.